# Is 'Not my call' used literally?

Tags: usage

It seems to me that the phrase ***'Not my call'*** is used mostly as ***'Not my desicion to make'***. Can I use it when someone is actually calling me to say it is not for me?

**Ex. 1.**

> "Mom's inviting everyone to the table. Are you coming?"
>
> "Not my call." *(This call is not for me because I don't want to go)*

**Ex. 2.**

> I rang a bell for all dogs to come and eat. Please, hold Betsy. It's not her call. She's already eaten too much. *(This call is not for Betsy because she's full)*

If it is not used, can you provide a better alternative?

Comment: It does not sound idiomatic.  Particularly in the first example, I would not understand what the speaker meant.  In "it is/isn't my call", *call* always means *decision*, not a literal call.

Comment: What does example 1 mean? That you can't choose whether to go for dinner, or you don't want dinner, or something else?

Comment: The first example just looks like a "non-sequitur". The only meaning I can assign it is *There's no point in asking me if I'm coming to the table, because I don't have the power to decide whether I will or not* (with the strong implication that whoever *does* control whether you can go to the table hasn't specifically told you if you can or not, otherwise you'd simply reply either "Yes, I'm coming" or "No - I'm not allowed to"). The second example is complete nonsense.

Comment: By the way, if I wanted to refer to a literal phone call, or a summoning, I would say something like "The call isn't for me" or "I am not being called."

Comment: @Stuart F I've updated the question with meanings I imply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, but it would be pretty limited.  It would not be an idiomatic expression in the given example. We don't use "This is Betsy's call" to mean "This is the ringing of the bell for Betsy"

Perhaps in a game of bridge:

> Lesley: 2 clubs.
>
> Jo: Hold on Lesley, it's not your call. Sam was the dealer so she gets to go first.

Even then "turn" might be more common.